# I am 90 KGS plz help me to lose

Tags: recommended-daily-intake

My height is 5 11. In 2013 my weight is 65kg, after the delivery of my baby in 6. Months increased to 75kg, in 2015 Jan I got 88kg &. I went to weightloss center lost 7 kg in one year,then I stopped. now I increased to 90kg. Daily I promise to eat low calorie diet but I can't. When i am cooking I use to eat whatever in the cupboard. I am unable to control this habit . What can I do to keep my promise & to lose weight

Comment: First step is habit formation. If you don't have control over eating habits, there's nothing anyone could do to help.

Answer (score 0):

try to get rid of sugar from your diet. maybe sounds tough but it helps to reduce all kinds of problems and work out regularly. it does not have to be a super hard gym program but some exercise(treadmill, situps, walking instead of driving if the distance is reasonable), no sugar should do and idk try to keep the same food that you eat on a table. best is not to take too drastic actions or diets. patience and a regular workout I mean exercise every day.

no sugar means no coke, soft drinks, chocolates, syrup sweets etc. and don't fall for sweeteners its a trap. ad once you stop using it don't use it. because even one chocolate bar later makes me crave for more.